# Uploads to network share are faster than my ISP allows

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn, network-shares

I am currently working from home and connect to my workplace via VPN. I have a 16k down/2k up internet connection.

Whenever I upload a file to a network share, my upload speed sits at roughly 1.6 Megabytes/s. This is all fine and good, but my ISP only allows 250 Kilobyte/s.

When I move a file from one location to another inside of the network share, the file copies at around 230 Kilobytes/s, which I suppose means, that it is downloading the file to my computer and then uploading it to the new location. This also falls in line with what I expect, since it is bottelnecked by my upload speed.

Can anyone point me to some documentation how a file can technically upload faster than my ISP allows or explain what is happening?

Comment: You cannot move data faster than your ISP allows (for any ISP situation I have seen). So then for your description above, are you moving from one network location to another network location inside the VPN?  That would explain what you see.

Comment: @John - "When I move a file from one location to another inside of the network share, the file copies at around 230 Kilobytes/s"

Comment: There must be something different about your ISP and maybe they have changed things.

Comment: @John I totally agree that it is not possible to do that. I have just tested again. A speed test confirms that my upload speed is 2Mbit/s so that implies that nothing has changed for me.